# Convert old procedural PHP function into Model-View-Controller (MVC) in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am new to Model-View-Controller and I started coding in Codeigniter. I am basically converting my project into MVC, however, I encountered this function(below) which I would like to split into MVC. I have 100s of functions like this and if I get the best approach to this, I will be able to convert the rest of my functions into MVC myself.

This function contains PHP, Mysql, and HTML everything in one. Like we split queries and HTML separately, I also want to do it using Codeingiter framework.
Even if you cannot answer using codeigniter default functions, just tell me how to split.

Here it is :

```
 $fetch_projections = mysql_query("SELECT issue_id, emp_name, employeeId, sum(actualHoursPerDay) as ss FROM day_projections WHERE date = '$today' GROUP BY employeeId ORDER BY emp_name ASC");
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($fetch_projections)) {
        $maes_array[] = $r['issue_id'];
        $all_maes_for_emp = implode($maes_array);
        // echo $r['emp_name'] $r['ss'].'<br/>'; 

        $split_up_query = mysql_query("SELECT issue_id, actualHoursPerDay FROM day_projections WHERE date = '$today' AND emp_name = '" . $r['emp_name'] . "'");
        while ($t = mysql_fetch_array($split_up_query)) {
            $kk[] = $t['issue_id'] . ' = ' . $t['actualHoursPerDay'] . ' hrs';
        }
        $pp = implode(', ', $kk);
        $cap = round((((8 - $r['ss']) / 8) * 100), 2);
        echo '<tr><td>' . $r['emp_name'] . '</td><td>' . $cap . '%</td><td>' . $r['ss'] . ' hrs</td><td>' . $pp . '</td></tr>';
        unset($maes_array);
        unset($kk);
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit funky and not optimal. You are recalling a sql query and iterating where you dont need to. What I would do to fix it is take advantage of MYSQL's `GROUP_CONCAT`, then convert it all into MVC using Codeigniter. Here's my approach:

**Model:** *application\models\My_model.php*

> The Model represents your data structures. Typically your model
>   classes will contain functions that help you retrieve, insert, and
>   update information in your database.

```
class My_model extends CI_MODEL{

    function fetch_projections($today){
        $this->db->select("emp_name, sum(actualHoursPerDay) as ss, GROUP_CONCAT( issue_id,'=',actualHoursPerDay,'hrs' SEPARATOR ';') as pp");
        $this->db->from("day_projections");
        $this->db->where("date" , $today);
        $this->db->group_by("employeeId");
        $this->db->order_by("emp_name" , "asc");
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

}
```

**Controller:** *application\controllers\My_controller.php*

> The Controller serves as an intermediary between the Model, the View,
>   and any other resources needed to process the HTTP request and
>   generate a web page.

```
class My_controller extends CI_Controller {

    function calculate() {
        $today = "0000-00-00"; // or whatever code you have to come up for "today"
        $this->load->model("My_model");
        $projections_results = $this->My_model->fetch_projections($today);
        if ($projections_results) {
            foreach ($projections_results as $projection) {
                $projection->cap = round((((8 - $projection->ss) / 8) * 100), 2);
            }
        }
        $view_data["results"] = $projections_results;
        $this->load->view("my_view", $view_data);
    }

}
```

**View:** *application\views\my_view.php*

> The View is the information that is being presented to a user. A View
>   will normally be a web page, but in CodeIgniter, a view can also be a
>   page fragment like a header or footer. It can also be an RSS page, or
>   any other type of "page".

```
<table>
    <?php foreach ($results as $res) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $res->emp_name ?></td>
            <td><?= $res->cap ?>%</td>
            <td><?= $res->ss ?>hrs</td>
            <td><?= $res->pp ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Source: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/overview/mvc.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: The code gave me zero error. It's highly appreciable that you could understand my part of the code without complete project and could able to convert and run it so flawlessly. Thanks you so much.

Comment: I have accepted the answer. And many thanks for optimizing the code. 

Just small question relating it, you had used codeigniter based functions for running queries.
Can't we use mysql or mysqli based traditional queries?
It's irritating to understand and apply such functions. I mean, I could write my queries in 1 or 2 lines but because of codeigniter, I am writing much extra code.
Also tell if we can use mysqli_query then what is the name of the first parameter we are to give?
I know mysql_query is deprecated in codeigniter.

Comment: yea you can still write out plain mysql if you like, you would just need to use `$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM whatever")` . However I wouldnt recomend it. Its up to you, check it out here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you know Obect oriented programming ,php 5.5+ and Codeigniter v2+.
The code(below) shows how to implement the MVC in codeigniter.
Under codeigniter framework there are many folders like models,views,controllers
,config etc.put these(below code) as mentioned.

Model(database related stuff/queries etc) Example_model.php.
Put this file under 'application/models' folder

```
class Example_model extends CI_Model{

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function getData($today=""){

$query="SELECT issue_id, emp_name, employeeId, sum(actualHoursPerDay) as ss 
FROM day_projections WHERE date = $today GROUP BY employeeId ORDER BY 
emp_name ASC";

$result=$this->db->query($query);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        foreach ($result->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        return $data;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }

}


}
```

NOTE: you must autoload 'database' library in autoload.php in 'application/config' folder in your project directory or load it in constructor above like this.

```
 $this->load->library('database);
```

---

Controller(Helps to control the user requests/data flow/routing etc )Example.php ,put this file under "application/controllers".

```
class Example extends CI_Controller {

   function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

  $this->load->model('Example_model');

   }


public function index(){

$today=now();
$result=$this->Example_model->getData($today);

$this->load->view('index_view',['result'=>$result]);

  }


  }
```

---

View(Presentation/ user visible pages etc) index_view.php,put this file under "application/views".

```
<body>
     <table>
           <tr>1</tr>
           <tr>2</tr>

           <?php   foreach($result as $r):    ?>
           <td><?=     $r->emp_name    ?></td>

           <?php      endforeach;     ?>

     </table>


</body>
```

NOTE: For more abstract info. http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/overview/at_a_glance.html